# How to filter items in a table with all checked variables in ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Im trying to filter items in a table based on checked values but I am only able to filter one of the values at a time. What should I do to filter all the checked values?

This is the JavaScript:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('employees', function(){});
});

App.EmployeesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return App.EMPLOYEES;
  }
});

App.EmployeesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

    inFinance: false, 
    inMarketing: false,

    filtered: function(){
      var inFinance = this.get('inFinance');
      var inMarketing = this.get('inMarketing');
          var model = this.get('model');
      var newModel = model;

      if(inFinance){
        newModel = model.filterBy('department', 'Finance');
      }
      if(inMarketing){
        newModel = model.filterBy('department', 'Marketing');
      }

        return newModel;
    }.property('inFinance', 'inMarketing')
});

App.EMPLOYEES=[
{
  name: 'Ricky',
  department: 'Finance'
},
{
  name:'George',
  department:'Marketing'
},
{
  name:'Jonah',
  department: 'Finance'
}
];
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.1/normalize.css">
    <script src="http://builds.handlebarsjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/handlebars-v2.0.0.js"></script>
  <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.9.1/ember.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" sytle='padding:'>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      {{#link-to 'index' tagName='a' classNames='navbar-brand'}}Test{{/link-to}}
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>{{#link-to 'employees' tagName='a'}}Employees{{/link-to}}</li></li>

      </ul>

    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>



      <div class="container">
      {{outlet}}
      </div>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" sytle='padding:'>
      Created by the almighty burrito. EmberJs Testing 2015
    </nav>
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">

    <h1 style='padding:30px'>{{#link-to 'employees' tagName='a'}}Click for Employees{{/link-to}}</h3>

  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="employees">
    <h3 style='padding:15px'> Filter</h3>
    {{input type='checkbox' checked=inFinance}} Finance
    {{input type='checkbox' checked=inMarketing}} Marketing

    <h2 class="sub-header" >Employees</h2>
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>name</th>
              <th>department</th>
            </tr>
          <tbody>
          {{#each employee in filtered}}
            <tr>
              <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
              <td>{{employee.department}}</td>
          {{/each}}

          </thead>
  </script>





</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance! Here is the jsBin [Here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/papobo/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: [Ember CLI](http://ember-cli.com) is the recommended way to start new Ember apps, incidentally.

Comment: I am using Ember-cli but this is because of jsbin purposes. If you have a better answer using ember-cli please feel free to do so!

Comment: Ah, no there’s no difference between globals-based Ember and Ember CLI for this question, glad you’re already on CLI. Hopefully someone works out a way to make Ember CLI-compatible JS Bins soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s one way to filter based on an attribute matching multiple values. I added an accounting department for more variety.

```
var newModel = model;

var matchAgainst = [];

if(inFinance){
  matchAgainst.push('Finance');
}
if(inMarketing){
  matchAgainst.push('Marketing');
}
if(inAccounting){
  matchAgainst.push('Accounting');
}

if (!Ember.isEmpty(matchAgainst)) {
  newModel = newModel.filter(function(person) {
    return matchAgainst.indexOf(person.department) != -1;
  });
}
```

[JS Bin example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qebacoqusu/2/edit)

Comment: Oops, I mistyped. Try it now.

Comment: I am still getting the same result, it's not showing anything if both departments are checked

Comment: Oh, you didn’t say you wanted to filter based on an `OR` of the values. So if none of the boxes are checked, you want all the values to show, but if both are checked, you also want all the values to show?

Comment: That is correct, I would like to see all the people that work in the selected departments. If there where 4 departments, for example: marketing, finance, accounting, and HR. If finance and marketing are the only ones checked then I would like to see al the people that work in those 2 departments. If non are checked then show all the employees.

Comment: Okay, check it out now.